# Can't get data from API endpoint

Tags: json, postman

I'm trying to get cryptocurrencies logos from https://coinmarketcap.com

According to documentation I can get them from this endpoint `/v1/cryptocurrency/info`

It's also required that API Key should be supplied via a custom header named `X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY`.

I tried to make an API call in Postman, but it's returning bad request.

My key: `X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY`

My API Key value: `c972ac08-519e-47e5-8cd8-23e6230289f3`

I can fetch cryptocurrencies lists, but not metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to provide the cryptocurrency symbols for which you want the details `symbol=BTC,ETH` as part of the query. Refer screenshot below.
The `logo` key is present inside the respective cryptocurrency response.

```
"logo": "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1.png"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works. Could I please ask one more question? What query will be right if I need all 100 cryptocurrencies logos?

Comment: @Abrcd18 I doubt it's possible via a single API. You can use v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest to get all cryptocurrencies, but there is no logo information in it. So you need the second API calls with all currency symbols

Comment: Could you please explain how can I get all symbols or I can only get the details of specific symbols?